# Unix storing files in a variable one at the time

Tags: unix

how to store multiple files in a variable 1 at the time.

```
for f in *.biz
do
file="$(ls *.biz)"
echo " $file"
done
```

but here is the output

```
 minimum.biz
 maximum.biz
 milan.biz
 ritz.biz <-------------1
 minimum.biz
 maximum.biz
 milan.biz
 ritz.biz <-------------2
 minimum.biz
 maximum.biz
 milan.biz
 ritz.biz  <------------3
 minimum.biz
 maximum.biz
 milan.biz
 ritz.biz  <------------4
```

well as you can see the program stored all of them  at once and for no reason the program iterate 3 more times.

any ideas??? thanks in advance

Comment: what shell? Bash?

Comment: Ksh and Zsh, the first one will be my priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four `.biz` files.  Therefore `for f in *.biz; do ... done` will form a loop that iterates four times.  `$f` be assigned values `minimum.biz` in 1st iteration, `maximum.biz` in 2nd iteration, `milan.biz` in 3rd iteration and `ritz.biz` in 4th iteration respectively.

Inside the loop, i.e.

```
file="$(ls *.biz)"
echo " $file"
```

$file is assigned the four file names, and the `echo` statement prints all four `.biz` files names.

Please try this and you will understand more:

```
for f in *.biz
do
echo "-- Inside loop $f --"
file="$(ls *.biz)"
echo " $file"
done
```

**Update:**
From your comments I assume you simply wants to iterates over the files and the below modified code should work:

```
for f in *.biz
do
echo " $f"
done
```

Comment: @ Kenneth thanks for your reply, i'm trying to store the files one at the time. In the variable, then i can apply a set of command on that variable. Once it's done the script store another file in that variable....

Comment: @Driven  Please see my update to the answer. I am not sure if you are confused with "that variable" you referred to - there are actually two variables `$f` and `$file`.  For simplicity I choose `$f`.

Comment: thanks a lot really simple and easy, I have nothing else to say.